# Re-write TensorFlow into Keras with tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wan to re-write TensorFlow code into Keras. I just wonder if you can use for this purpose the `tf.keras.layers` to just replace the `tf.layers`?

Like

```
tf.layers.max_pooling2d()
```

to:

```
tf.keras.layers.max_pooling2d()
```

Can I re-write TensorFlow to Keras in this way?

Does this define a proper Keras model where you can use the `model.fit` method?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you meant `tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D`, which is a class, not a function. If I got your point, it shouldn't be an issue. There are some minor difference in syntax, but nothing serious. Besides, `tf.keras.layers` is a direct substitute for `tf.layers`. As per official docs, `tf.layers` are wrappers around tf.keras.layers. [For example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L28), convolutional layers in Layers API inherit from `tf.keras.layers`.

```py
@tf_export('layers.Conv1D')
class Conv1D(keras_layers.Conv1D, base.Layer):
  """1D convolution layer (e.g. temporal convolution).
```

Even more so, Layers API is deprecated and will be removed from TF 2.0.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but:

    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(
          100,
          activation=tf.nn.relu,
          kernel_initializer='uniform',
          input_shape=(input_dim,)))
  ....

Comment: See from here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-keras?hl=de#design_and_train_the_model

Comment: So if my tf.layers are just wrappers of tf.keras and I can write in keras style a model with tf.keras (see link), than this is what I asked for?!

Comment: Yes, you can define any `tf.keras.Model` with `tf.keras.layers`. And just as I said, starting from tf version 2.0 you'll have no other option, than to use `tf.keras.layers` to define any model. Creating any layer from scratch is the only exception

Comment: ok. Thanks. So I think then it is relatively easy to rewrite a tensorflow code to keras!